# How to write this Java snippet more clean

Tags: java

I have written this Java snippet which uses a listener to detect whether a certain key has been entered.

It's a bit rough around the edges and was wondering if there was a better way of writing it (eg. I want the out put text to appear in JTextField-print, at the moment "print" is a little rectangle box...I want it to be a blocked and the text to appear into it)?

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2{
    
    public Test2() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setSize(300,300);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel jpanel= new JPanel();
        jpanel.add(new JLabel("Enter your name:"));
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField("    ");
        jpanel.add(nameField);
        JTextArea print = new JTextArea("");
        jpanel.add(print);
    
        nameField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyChar() == 65) {
                    print.setText("A was typed!");
                }
                
                if (e.getKeyChar() == 66) {
                    System.out.println("B was typed!");
                }
            }
            
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Formatting**

There is a lot of vertical space between statements that don't add any readability.

**Printing characters**

Is there any business specific case that you only print letters A and B? If not, it would be cleaner to just print all characters that were typed:

```java
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    String statement = e.getKeyChar() + " was typed!";
    print.setText(statement);
    System.out.println(statement);
}
```

Or you could provide some checking to print only letters:

```java
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char typedCharacter = e.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(typedCharacter)) {
        String statement = e.getKeyChar() + " was typed!";
        print.setText(statement);
        System.out.println(statement);
    }
}
```

**Override**

You should add `@Override` annotation to every method that you override. It [informs the compiler that the element is meant to override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)

**Naming**

Test2 class is poorly named. NameAsker or something like this would be better.

**TODO Auto-generated method stub**

It does not provide any useful information to reader. It should be deleted.

**Corrected version**

This is how I would correct this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NameAsker().ask();
    }
}

class NameAsker {
    void ask() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setSize(300,300);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jpanel= new JPanel();
        jpanel.add(new JLabel("Enter your name:"));
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField("    ");
        jpanel.add(nameField);
        JTextArea print = new JTextArea("");
        jpanel.add(print);

        nameField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char typedCharacter = e.getKeyChar();
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(typedCharacter)) {
                    String statement = e.getKeyChar() + " was typed!";
                    print.setText(statement);
                    System.out.println(statement);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
        });

        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it more compact you can use `KeyAdapter`. So won't need to implement useless methods

Answer (score 2):

instead of `if(e.getKeyChar() == number)`

you can use `switch`

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
        case 65: print.setText("A was typed!"); break;
        case 66: print.setText("B was typed!"); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that...also, is there a way to have one method and remove the unimplemented method in new KeyListener

Comment: @Learner, no, there is no `KeyListenerAdapter` avaiable

Comment: @Learner https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow more letters than A and B, you can do this:

1 - Declare a String in the class:

```
private static String chars = "ABCDEFG12345";
```

2 - Use this `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` method:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if (chars.indexOf(c) != -1) // If chars contains the char
        print.setText(c + " was typed!");
    else print.setText("");
}
```

Full code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {
    private static String chars = "ABCDEFG12345";

    public Test2() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setSize(300,300);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel jpanel= new JPanel();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your name:");
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField("");
        JTextArea print = new JTextArea("");

        jpanel.add(label);
        jpanel.add(nameField);
        jpanel.add(print);
    
        nameField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (chars.indexOf(c) != -1) // If chars contains the char
                    print.setText(c + " was typed!");
                else print.setText("");
            }
            
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
            
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();
    }
}
```